# arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False not working when using arcpy.AddJoin_management

Tags: arcpy, python

I would like to add a join on a layer while keeping the original fields names. I thought setting the `qualifiedFieldNames` environment parameter to `False` would do the job, as the documentation says, but it has no effect.

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

input_fc = os.path.join("C:\\", "temp", "GEODEV.sde", "dataset", "my_feature_class")
join_table = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(os.path.join("C:\\", "temp", "to_join.csv"), "in_memory", "join_table")
layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_fc, "in_memory\\layer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management(layer, "MY_IN_FIELD", join_table, "MY_JOIN_FIELD")

print([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(layer)])

>>>'["GEODEV.dataset.field1", "GEODEV.dataset.field2", "GEODEV.dataset.field3", "join_table.fieldA", "join_table.fieldB", "join_table.fieldC"]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

T.h.a.n.k you a.l.l for your h.e.l.p!

Comment: What if you make the layer permanent by copying to disk?

Comment: I dont want to... then I am using a SearchCursor to output json strings only. Its part of a Geoprocessing Service, I dont want to save the join.

Comment: Further to @BERA comment, could you do a test by persisting to disk? Put CopyFeatures in after your addjoin, writing to disk, and do the listfields off that result. It looks like you're doing everything correctly based on the doc. The result of this test may show a bug or something else?

Comment: Why you didn't set workspace in the code? arcpy.env.workspace = ...

Comment: I confirm that when using CopyFeatures_management on the layer after the join, the fields are as wanted. However, is there a posibility to have the fields names correctly written without having to save to disk?

Comment: @wetland because I am using complete absolute path to refer to feature classes

Comment: @BelowtheRadar interesting. In that case its either a bug, or simply "that's the way it works". I dont think there is anything more you can do to force it. You may need to log a tech support call to get the 100% answer

Comment: @KHibma yes that's what I fear, that must be the way it works

Comment: You could copy into in_memory workspace so you dont need to copy to disk

Comment: @BERA yeah... but then the layer is not a SDE layer anymore... and the sql_clause (None, ORDER BY xx) would not be supported for it... what I need... ouch it's getting very complicated

Comment: Please do not include chit chat like thanks in your questions.  The way to say thanks is to upvote and/or accept answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the help file for the AddJoin tool, under the [Usage](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm#ESRI_USAGES_87DF93B28BCB4A428CC657614EB4FE79) section it indicates that the qualified fields name environment property applies to the tool when trying to save a copy, so until you copy your features your joins will have table names.

Comment: Lol... of course it's doc'd. I was reading the `qualifiedFieldNames` doc and didn't see anything about needing to make the copy. Good eye.